# Using lynx in a bash script

Tags: html, bash, text, scripting, lynx

I am trying to write a bash script that will convert all html files in a
directory to text files.

I figured I could do this using lynx.
Such as...
   lynx -dump index.1.html > index.1.txt

This command works perfectly fine in the shell, but when I try implementing it in
the script, I get an error saying: ./txtFiles/./.txt: No such file or directory

Here is my code...

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir txtFiles
for file in ./
do 
   lynx --dump $file > ./txtFiles/$file.txt

done
```

Anyone know how I would be able to get this to run properly?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably want `for file in ./*`, not `for file in ./`

Answer (score 2):

How about **for file in *.html**?

The "for file in" part doesn't know that you want it to read all the files in the current directory. In fact, it doesn't "know" anything about files at all -- it is just expecting a list of words. If you give it the *glob* "*.html", bash will create that list for you, based on all files in the current directory that match that pattern.

Answer (score 0):

you need to give $file a file in return but `for file in ./` gives the folder to $file which is undesired and is causing the error.
Hope I helped.